# I get an error when trying to connect to an oracle database. How to fix it?

Tags: go, oracle-autonomous-db

dbInfo := DbInfo{
Username:       "ADMIN",
Password:       "Ddbstjrld1!a",
Server:         "adb.ap-seoul-1.oraclecloud.com",
Port:           "1522",
Service:        "gee9edfb92f3cf6_redglqwayxqefhhf_high.adb.oraclecloud.com",
WalletLocation: "/Users/temp1/Desktop/Wallet_REDGLZWEYXQEFHHF",
}

```
dbString := fmt.Sprintf(`user="%v" password="%v" connectString="tcps://%s:%s/%s?wallet_location=%s"`, dbInfo.Username, dbInfo.Password, dbInfo.Server, dbInfo.Port, dbInfo.Service, dbInfo.WalletLocation)

db, err := sql.Open("godror", dbString)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}
defer db.Close()

r, err := db.Exec(`CREATE TABLE member_table (
    seq        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    mb_id     VARCHAR(20),
    mb_pw    VARCHAR(100),
    address   VARCHAR(100),
    mb_tell    VARCHAR(20),  
     PRIMARY KEY(seq)
   ) ENGINE= MYISAM CHARSET=utf8;`)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}

fmt.Println(r)
```

I am using oracle for the first time. I checked the manual and followed it, but I can't solve it.

```
Error running query
ORA-00000: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 0x0001): tried: 'libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/temp1/project/oracleDatabase/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file)". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#macos for help
temp@temp-MacBookPro oracleDatabase %
```

When connecting through dbeaver, it works normally, but when connecting with the above code in golang, the following error is returned.

I've been struggling for several days, if you show me a simple example, I think I can study while analyzing it, can you help me?

Comment: Check this which shows examples of connecting to an Autonomous Database. https://technology.amis.nl/software-development/connecting-go-application-to-oracle-database-on-prem-and-autonomous-with-and-without-oracle-client-libraries/

Comment: In the example, a local database is used. I want to create and connect to an autonomous database in the oracle console. In the example, there are server, port, and service fields in the db information map. How can I find these information?

Comment: For example the server field is ocid right? service is databasename?

Comment: It also has sample code for the Autonomous Database, see the paragraph that starts with "When the Oracle Database that I want to interact with needs to connected to using an Oracle Wallet – such as in the case of an Oracle Autonomous Database ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: As pointed out by [Christopher Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799035/christopher-jones), `goracle` has been deprecated because of trademark issues. The replacement is [`godror`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/godror/godror)

To use it, run:

```
go get github.com/godror/godror@latest
```

and then install Oracle Client libraries. [Follow its documentation](https://github.com/godror/godror#connection) to make a connection.

As per `godror` documentation, you must be aware of:

> godror is cgo package. If you want to build your app using godror, you
> need gcc (a C compiler).

---

As per the mentioned error, you need to import oracle driver [`goracle`][3] for `database/sql` to work with an oracle database.

```
import (
    "database/sql"

    // Import the Oracle driver
    _ "gopkg.in/goracle.v2"
)
```

P.S.: I would suggest to add line number in question statement which raised that error so that it can be debugged easily.

Comment: Don't do this.  The package got renamed to godror and has been enhanced for some time. https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/godror/godror  Also, changing the import won't help solve the DPI-1047 issue.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherJones for pointing out. I have updated my answer. Much appreciated. madol please rectify these changes since you already accepted my answer. Thanks.